# Videojs-chromecast plugin fails to launch on Android platform (but works on PC platform)

Tags: android, html, chromecast, video.js

I've built an html5-video webpage that uses video-js and its chromecast-plugin. When I use the resulting cast button on video-js player's control-bar, when running on Chrome-browser on Android, it fails to completely transfer over to the TV's screen.  The failing symptom is that only a large blue cast-icon is visible in the center of the TV screen.  It fails on Android, each and every time I try it.  (My Android is version 7.1.1, on a Google Nexus-9 tablet.)
And when it fails to completely cast over to the TV, the cast-icon-button on the video-js control-bar turns red, which I assume means that the chromecast-plugin 'knows' that it failed. (The videojs-chromecast-plugin is version 2.0.8)

My chromecast device is a 2nd-generation chromecast-dongle from Google.

[ From a PC-platform, the video-js chromecast-plugin's cast-button works perfectly every time. That PC-platform is Windows-10, using the newest version of Chrome browser (Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)) ]

So, could someone with Android and a chromecast device please test my
webpage and report whether it works or whether they too fail with a large
blue cast-icon image in center of their TV-screen.

(Note: I've googled for symptom of the blue cast-icon in center of TV, and
find various reports of this exact symptom, on various platforms.  But
none of those problem posts ever end with a solution, so I've concluded
that this is a known open issue.)

My webpage that is failing is located here:
https://weasel.firmfriends.us/HTMLVideoFromCloud/

[ You can see the page's html and javascript via "view page source"
in the browser (right-click anywhere on the page, outside of the
video-js viewer) ]

(EDIT#1) Ok, some extra clarification: The problem casting from Android happens ONLY when I use the cast-button at right-end of videojs-viewer's control bar.
But, I have found an alternative cast-button on Android, that CAN successfully cast my page to the TV.  I don't recall exactly what I did to get this extra button to start appearing, but it will appear for a few seconds in the upper-left client-area of the video-js player window rendering my webpage. This 'workaround' doesn't completely solve my issue, because the goal is to get videojs-chromecast-plugin's cast-button to work.  Also, other people viewing the page from Android may not know how to get that alternate cast-button.

(EDIT#2) I've tested now from two different tablets...both fail.
(1) Android version 7.1.1, on a Google Nexus-9 tablet
(2) Android version 5.1.1, on a Google Nexus-10 tablet

TIA...